# Select only ids with tags that matches an array exactly

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table of ids and tags

```
id  |   tags    
1   |   apples  
1   |   pears   
2   |   apples  
2   |   pears   
2   |   oranges 
3   |   apples  
3   |   pears   
3   |   oranges 
3   |   lemons
```

I want to query only for ids that have the tags ('apples', 'pears', oranges').
So the desired output in this case is only id 2.

After reading other similar posts, I have tried the following query statement in mysql:

```
SELECT 
     id 
FROM table 
WHERE tags IN ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges') 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags)=3;
```

But this returns both id 2 & 3, and I only want id 2 in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id 
FROM t
GROUP BY id 
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tags IN('apples', 'pears', 'oranges') THEN tags END)=3
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tags NOT IN('apples', 'pears', 'oranges') THEN tags END) = 0;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/090f11/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: I think in `MySQL` it can be written -> `HAVING COUNT(tags in(...) = 3 ..` no need for `CASE` , but +1 .

Comment: Will this work if an id has two apples, a pear and and an orange?

Comment: @jarlh, in that case, we need to add `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @sagi, I'm not really familiar with MySQL syntax and SQL fiddle is not working properly so I don't have the time to test that.

Comment: Me neither , I just know MySQL take a boolean expression as `1` and `0` , so just the condition should be enough:)

Comment: I'm getting an error when passing my list in the IN LIST in HAVING clause. I'm using it like this:

    HAVING 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] IN(SELECT [Text] FROM @Labels) THEN l.[Text] END)=@LabelsCount
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN l.[Text] NOT IN(SELECT [Text] FROM @Labels) THEN l.[Text] END) = 0;
I get following error:
"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."